# User Sql Server Compact 3.5 as a data source in Excel 2007/2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I'd like to provide users the ability to connect to a Sql Server Compact SDL from Excel to do some analyses.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this and would like a little help.

Are there any addins/updates that add this option to the "From other sources" under the Data ribbon?  Is OLEDB the only way?  And if so, how the heck do you do it that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option will be a macro - see this sample: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2008/04/import-sql-compact-data-to-excel.html

Comment: Sad, sad.  I guess this is the best option.